# Regex extracting tokens from a dot delimited string

Tags: regex

I am trying to find **regex** expressions that will accomplish the following

Given sample string: **This.is.my.sample.string**

1.) I need a regular expression that will get me only **This**

2.) I need another regular expression that will get me only **is**

3.) I need another regular expression that will get me only **my**

4.) I need another regular expression that will get me only **sample**

5.) I need another regular expression that will get me only **string**

So basically I need **5** different regular expressions to get all **5** delimited strings.

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes to all 5 questions.

Comment: Whichever language you are using probably has a `split` function that would come in handy for this

Comment: you don't need regex to do that. learn some string functions. which programming language are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not have split available unfortunately. Is there any other way without split?

Comment: What is the language in what you are coding?

Comment: Its a crippled version of LINQ. Only regex expressions are supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `^([^.]*)`, string: `([^.]*$)`, is: `\.([^.]*)`, my: `\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)`, sample: `([^.]*)\.[^.]*$`.

Comment: I am trying these on http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html and some of them are not working.

Comment: uncheck all the boxses, and it does not support captures they will work if the engine supports captures

Comment: Its very close. Thank you so much. Somehow
\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)  is capturing .is.my
([^.]*)\.[^.]*$  is capturing sample.string
Could there be a problem with this online regex-tester?

Comment: it is capturing `my` but matching `.is.my`, see here: http://regex101.com/r/bQ8dJ9